# Displaying two values on the same row in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I'd like to be able to display the name and price of the product on the same line. Right now, it's displayed as:
Product name
Product price

I've tried adding a linearlayout with the orientation horizontal, tried using weightsum / weight and can't figure out how to make it show properly, like in a normal menu, with the name at the left and the price at the right. I also tried setting their gravity, but it always displays them on two rows. I'd like to display them as such:

Product name...........................Product Price

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:background="#ffffff">

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/Remove"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
          android:text="Remove product(s)" />

      </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How I'm adding the items:

```
oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put(PROD_NAME, name);
  map.put(PROD_PRICE, price);
  oslist.add(map);

   adapter = new SimpleAdapter(shopping_cart.this, oslist,
            R.layout.shoppingcart,
            new String[] {PROD_NAME, PROD_PRICE}, new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.Price});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's often easier to create a layout like this using a `RelativeLayout` as it gives you more control over the placement of views. You would give the name element `layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and the price element `layout_alignParentRight="true"` (and probably `layout_gravity="right"` to right align the text).

EDIT

Here's what your XML might look like. You won't actually need the `layout_gravity` attribute if you are using `layout_width="wrap_parent"`, and I've omitted the remove button because I'm not sure where you want it to be.

This layout allows the name and price to overlap if they are too long - probably the best option to fix that is to put the name element *after* the price element in the XML and add `layout_toLeftOf="@id/Price"` to it. That forces it to wrap the name instead of overlap the price.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:background="#ffffff">

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Aye, I sorted that part, was just wondering if I need the linear for the button anymore or not. I'd like it to be at the bottom center of the entire thing, not sure how it will react when the list becomes scrollable. o.o

Comment: is there a way to achieve this for `ListView`?